# Quartz.NET Scheduler, initalization in each scheduler.Start()

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have several Robot Jobs that extends to abstract `RobotJob` class, sharing log files, configurations, pause/continue options etc... I'm trying adopt `Quartz.NET` to schedule these jobs. I'm also trying to make it work with least amount of code/structure modification. However, I have two intertwined problems:

1) I need a parameterless constructor in `MyRobotJob` since `scheduler.Start()` constructs a new `MyRobotJob` object, but I don't want a parameterless constructor.

2) Since `scheduler.Start()` creates a new `MyRobotJob`, there is an infinite loop stemming from the calls of the constructors. I know that this design is problematic, and I wonder how can I modify it so there will only be single `MyRobotJob` object that will run according to the schedule.

*What I tried:* I defined an abstract method that returns `IJob` in `RobotJob`. I implemented it in `MyRobotJob` which returned another class `MyRobotRunner`, implementing `IJob`. But if I do it like that in a separate class, I cannot make use of my logging methods in `RobotJob`. A simplified version of the code is like this:

```
public abstract class RobotJob
{
    public string Cron { get; set; }
    public string LogFile { get; set; }
    public JobStatus Status { get; set; }
    // Properties, helpers...

    protected RobotJob(string name, string cron, string logFile = null)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.LogFile = logFile;
        this.Cron = cron;
        InitQuartzScheduler();
    }

    private void InitQuartzScheduler()
    {
        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(this.GetType())
            .WithIdentity(this.GetType().Name, "AJob")
            .Build();

        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(this.GetType().Name, "ATrigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithCronSchedule(Cron)
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        scheduler.Start(); // At this part, infinite loop starts
    }
}

[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class MyRobotJob : RobotJob, IJob
{
    // I need a parameterless constructor here, to construct
    public MyRobotJob()
        : base("x", "cron", "logFile")

    public MyRobotJob(string name, string cron, string logFile = null)
        : base(name, cron, logFile)
    {

    }
    public override void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call scheduler.Start() every time you add your job.  Make a method on a scheduler wrapper which will add your jobs and also will start your scheduler only once.

```
public class Scheduler : IScheduler
{
private readonly Quartz.IScheduler quartzScheduler;

public Scheduler()
{
  ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
  quartzScheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
  quartzScheduler.Start();
}

public void Stop()
{
  quartzScheduler.Shutdown(false);
}

public void ScheduleRoboJob()
{
  // your code here
  quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure that I have understood Scheduler correctly. Should we use Scheduler like singleton? I mean lets say I have two separate APIs , one for starting a job at required time, and one other for re-scheduling. Should I initiate Scheduler in both of them ?